# C++ - For loop not executed

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I don't understand why this for loop works

```
void managingTable(unsigned char table[256][256][1])
{
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x <= 255; x++)
    {
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y <= 255; y++)
        {
            doSomethingWithTable();
        }
    }
}
```

and this doesn't work exiting when y reaches 255 but with no iteration on x that remains 0

```
void managingTable(unsigned char table[256][256][1])
{
    unsigned int x = 0;
    unsigned int y = 0;

    for (x; x <= 255; x++)
    {
        for (y; y <= 255; y++)
        {
            doSomethingWithTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Also this doesn't work:

```
void managingTable(unsigned char table[256][256][1])
{
    unsigned int x = 0;
    unsigned int y = 0;

    for ( ; x <= 255; x++)
    {
        for ( ; y <= 255; y++)
        {
            doSomethingWithTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @0x5453  isn't that the answer?

Comment: Also, in your second example, `x` or `y` as the setup statement of the for loop has absolutely no effect, so it really should not be there.

Comment: @whydoubt yeah, this is why I reported third solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example declares a new `y` starting at 0 for each iteration of `x`.

Your second and third examples don't reset the value of `y` between iterations of `x`, so only the first `y` loop will execute.  The remaining `y` loops are skipped because `y` is already equal to 256.

Changing your second example as below should work:

```
void managingTable(unsigned char table[256][256][1])
{
    unsigned int x = 0;

    for (x; x <= 255; x++)
    {
        unsigned int y = 0;
        for (y; y <= 255; y++)
        {
            doSomethingWithTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You got it.  Either declare it inside the loop, or if declared outside then remember to reset it so it doesn't remain at 255 after the first iteration.